# Spring Batch: How to set time interval between each item

Tags: spring, spring-batch, sleep

i have to set a time interval in my job between each ItemWriter execution, as a Sleep.

I'm using a chunk task.

My code is:

```
<job id="job" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch">
    <step id="stepSendingEngine" parent="abstractStep">
        <tasklet>
            <chunk reader="Reader" writer="Writer" commit-interval="1" retry-limit="3" skip-limit="100" >
                <retryable-exception-classes>
                    <include class="MyException"/>
                   </retryable-exception-classes>
                <skippable-exception-classes>
                    <include class="MyException"/>
                </skippable-exception-classes>
            </chunk>
            <listeners>
                <listener ref="MySkipListener" />
            </listeners>
        </tasklet>
    </step>
    <listeners>
        <listener ref="myListenerSupport" />
    </listeners>
</job>
```

Comment: Wouldn't just putting a Thread.sleep after you have wrote using the ItemWriter help?

Comment: What is the delay for?

Comment: My job sends an email for each item. Since i've a problem with my email provider for sending limits, i need to wait for a time interval before to send next email.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is better to explain why you need this Sleep between Writer executions. It does not seem the right approach with Spring Batch.

But still, this job is executed by a single thread. You can put the sleep anywhere (for example: in the writer's implementation).